# Need advice for a SMTP server on Windows

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server

I would like to ask for advice about SMTP Servers.

I'd like to setup a small and simple server for a school project for which I need to send (or mock send) emails to a small amount of recipients.

So I need a simple, lightweight and Windows 10 compatible SMTP server.

I've already tried hMailServer but it didn't work, though I don't know why.
It had also messed with my OpenVPN configuration and I needed to reinstall it to have VPN tunelling working again.

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: do you have the option of running a vmware player instance on that windows machine? I would *personally* say you should *never* run an email server on windows... (unless your forced to use exchange)

Comment: I cannot afford to install a VMWare instance as the machine I am using is very low on memory. Is PaperCut a good alternative ?

Comment: Sorry - the only product I've ever used on a windows server (was years ago) was by a firm called Ipswitch, or exchange...